# Kendo UI Angular Grid Template With Router Link

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to use routerLink in grid template with id parameter?

Ex:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Garin" title="name" width="120" headerClass="THtheme">
                 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                    <a [routerLink]="../Details/{{dataItem.Id}}" >{{dataItem.Name}}</a>
                </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

when I try to do it I got error:

"Template parse errors.... Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"

Does anyone know if it possible and how? (not by code on click event....)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are trying to use a interpolation to assign a property which is not supported/allowed. ([Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3645))

But the `routerLink` directive can either take a string or an array of objects as parameter. ([Reference](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink))

The way to go, in this case, is to use the second variant:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../Details', dataItem.Id]">{{dataItem.Name}}</a>
```